# Steps for going live - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, web-deployment

I've been working on my website for some time now and I am now ready to push this brand new project to live.

I have already already read this [link on Symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html) with regards to what should be done, but I still think it is missing some details.  For example, it talks nothing about some of the commands that I run to get the site to work on live.

Currently this is what I would like to do to get this to work on live:

```
php composer.phar install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader --no-scripts
rm -rf app/cache/* 
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug 
php app/console assets:install web --symlink --env=prod
```

Is there anything else that needs to be done, for example, I don't want live to be able to execute my fixtures, nor do I want any users to be able to go to www.mysite.com/app_dev.php

Comment: You should also do `app/console cache:clear --env=prod`. In order not to access the `app_dev.php` file, there should be a [default security](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.4/web/app_dev.php#L12-L18) check.

Comment: @Touki, thanks for that.  I've added it to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [How to deploy a Symfony2 application](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment-tools.html).

Refer to link above. The typical steps taken while deploying a Symfony2 application include:

1. Upload your modified code to the live server;
2. Update your vendor dependencies (typically done via Composer, and may be done before uploading);
3. Running database migrations or similar tasks to update any changed data structures;
4. Clearing (and perhaps more importantly, warming up) your cache.

Common Post-Deployment Tasks

1. Configure your app/config/parameters.yml file
2. Update your vendors

   $ php composer.phar install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
3. Clear your Symfony cache

   $ php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
4. Dump your Assetic assets

   $ php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
5. Other things!

There may be lots of other things that you need to do, depending on your setup:

- Running any database migrations
- Clearing your APC cache
- Running assets:install (taken care of already in composer.phar install)
- Add/edit CRON jobs
- Pushing assets to a CDN
- ...

Comment: I actually had that same link in my original post ;-)  I strongly agree with what you've said, but I just wanted to be sure that there wasn't something that I've missed.  So far it doesn't look like it.  If that is the case, I'll just mark this answer as "accepted".  thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at capifony (https://github.com/everzet/capifony). Unfortunately the Website (http://capifony.org) is currently down..

Comment: I've heard about this.  When I've got more time I will try and take a look at this.  Hopefully there site is up by then.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to me is to have your project in  a versionning system like git or svn without the vendors dir of course ...

This way, your simply have to do :

```
1) git clone your project into the prod dir

2) php composer.phar install to install your vendors

2b) create the mysql user with correct login and password according to your parameters.yml

 3) php app/console doctrine:database:create to create your database with the credentials you set up in mysql

 4) php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force to perform the database tables creation
 5) testing the project :)
```

If you are not using a versionning system just upload your project to your server with an ftp software without the vendors directory ( it will be feeded by step 2) then perform 3rd , 4th and 5th steps !

you now should be able to reach you project through you domain url .

Comment: We do make use of git.  However it isn't really the problem with regards to the code, but more the scripts that need to run.  If I was to do step 2 of yours "php composer.phar install" it would wrongly install all my dev vendors such as Liip, WebProfilerBundle, FakerBundle just to name a few.  Also, I think using migrations would be much better than schema:update... just in case you want to roll back.

Comment: we use this process on every projects we deploy in production and everything is fine even on multiple schema update ( you still need to get your database synced with you code :) )